# How to stretch a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Given such a data frame:

```
V1     V2
x      3
y      2
z      4
...
```

I'd like to transform it to:

```
V1
x
x
x
y
y
z
z
z
z
```

Each element in `V1` has repeated for `n` times and `n` is the corresponding value in `V2`. Do you know how to implement it quickly without `for loop`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, where `x` is your data.frame:

```
data.frame(V1 = rep(x$V1, x$V2))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `expandRows`

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(df1, "V2")
#    V1
#1    x
#1.1  x
#1.2  x
#2    y
#2.1  y
#3    z
#3.1  z
#3.2  z
#3.3  z
```